# Wait for openCursor to finish in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have this code:

```
html5DB.indexedDB.addSomething = function(foo) {
    var db = html5DB.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(["something"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore("something");

    var isExisting = IsAlreadyExist(foo);
    // How to wait for that instruction to finish?

    if (!isExisting){
       var request = store.put({
           "text": foo,
           "timeStamp" : new Date().getTime()
       });
    }
};
```

I'm trying to understand how can I wait for the function `IsAlreadyExist` to finish. This function opens a cursor to iterate in the object store to determinate if a particular value exist.

Actually, there is no error, but I can't reach the code inside the `if (!isExisting)` because the value of the variable never changes.

This is the code of that second function:

```
function IsAlreadyExist(foo){
    var db = html5DB.indexedDB.db;
    var objectStore = db.transaction("something").objectStore("something");

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            if (cursor.value.text == foo)   
                return true;

            cursor.continue();
       }
    };

    return false;
}
```

Is there a way to wait for the end of the execution? Or maybe it is not a good way to proceed for checking if a value exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As IndexedDB is an asynchronous API you have to wait until operations are completed using callbacks.

First off we need to refactor the `IsAlreadyExist` method:

```
function IsAlreadyExist(foo, oncomplete) {
    var db = html5DB.indexedDB.db;
    var transaction = db.transaction("something");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("something");

    var exists = false;

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            if (cursor.value.text == foo) {
                exists = true;
                return;
            }

            cursor.continue();
       }
    };

    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
        oncompleted(exists);
    };
}
```

Now we'll refactor your other method:

```
html5DB.indexedDB.addSomething = function(foo) {
    IsAlreadyExist(foo, function (isExisting) {
        if (!isExisting){
           var db = html5DB.indexedDB.db;
           var trans = db.transaction(["something"], "readwrite");
           var store = trans.objectStore("something");

           var request = store.put({
               "text": foo,
               "timeStamp" : new Date().getTime()
           });
        }
    });
};
```

So here you'll see we're passing the function to execute when the cursor search is done as a callback, which receives an argument of the status.

This can start getting a bit ugly, which is why [Promise](http://promisesaplus.com/)'s are popular in JavaScript. I wrote a wrapper for IndexedDB that uses a Promise-based API called [db.js](https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js/).

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks !
 
I got this error though: `Uncaught TransactionInactiveError: The transaction has finished.` 

For fix it, I just moved the first 3 lines of the function `addSomething` to place them just above `store.put`.
That way, the transaction had the time to complete.

Comment: Ha my bad, should moved the transaction for the `put` call inside the callback. Fixed up the code to reflect that

Comment: you are a saviour. I was trying with async await but doesn't work out. this basic callback is only working. Thanks.  There is one typo, callback function name must be oncomplete **d** .. `function IsAlreadyExist(foo, oncompleted)`

Comment: Thanks. `onpenCursor.onsuccess` does not trigger on empty stores. `transaction.oncomplete` triggers on every store, including empty ones.